ssh reverse proxy - low port number
I have a service I can access on machine a
https://10.123.123.123:443
I want to access this on machine b via
https://127.0.0.1:443 & https://myethernetip:443
So this works (there is an intermediator jump host too!)
ssh -R 1443:10.123.123.123:443 me@myserver -J me@myjump:223
So now on myserver I can connect to localhost:1443 and get what I want....
Excellent accept the scripts have https hardcoded all over the place and other horrid things...
It would be much nicer to be able to do this:
ssh -R 443:10.123.123.123:443 me@myserver -J me@myjump:223
Which is thought would just require:
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/sbin/sshd
But it seems not!  What magic will allow the -R reverse proxy connect to a low port number please??
Thanks

Linux and macOS reserve ports 1-1023 for root. You should be able to sudo, though you'll have to specify the key(s) for these systems.
